# How to include startupTimeLimit in publish profile

Tags: asp.net-core

I don't have `web.config` in my project and I don't want to include it. So it's generated on publish.

I know I can include environment variables by adding them to the `Publish.pubxml`:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-8.0#set-the-environment
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-8.0#set-the-environment

Is there any way to modify a generated `web.config` on publish so I can include/modify `startupTimeLimit` property (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-8.0#attributes-of-the-aspnetcore-element) or any other properties of `aspNetCore` element?

Comment: web.config is just to configure the IIS and there is no approach to configure it from .net 8  code.

Comment: I didn't mean to configure it from the code, but rather by publish.pubxml. I was thinking there are some instructions on dotnet publish. The only way I can see it so far is to use an external utility which can modify xml document (web.config) as part of deployment process.

Comment: then this is not an asp.net core issue, per my understanding, you are now trying to find a solution from publishment pipeline or something similar...